# Ideal data type for an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, static

I'd like to store a static association between a key and a variable size array.

```
"foo" => ["bar", "awe"]  
"foo2" => ["bar2", "awe2", "gruh"]
```

This array will never change during the program execution, it is just a way to statically  associate a variable array of string with a string key.

Number of sub-arrays is very low (< 100).

How can I do that in pure **C**?

Comment: depends a bit on required performance how you would solve it.

Comment: You could look at some auxiliary programs for creating "minimal perfect hash functions". Run that over your keys. Then just store a static array of the payload data, as well as the hash function.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is a solution someone gave me:

```
struct
{
  const char *key;
  const char **values;
} key_to_values[] =
{
  { .key = "foo", .values = (const char *[]) { "val1", "val2", NULL } },
  { .key = "bar", .values = (const char *[]) { "val3", "val4", "val5", NULL } },
};
```

Comment: IMHO, this is a bad practice i.e. very unreadable code. Basically you are just creating a struct with two pointers as members and initializing those pointers with static arrays. I agree that it some what achieves you intention but again it is not using any built in construct of c. Writing a hash table as already written in another solution seems far better to me.

Comment: @fayyazkl: I don't see how what you are saying makes sense. Firstly, the above code is actually based purely and entirely on built-in constructs of C language. Secondly, C language has no such thing as "hash table" built into it, so your reference to "built-in" is completely unclear. Finally, for a constant data structure this is actually the best solution.

Comment: @AndreyT I believe you haven't read it in full context of the earlier answers. Above code is based on pure c constructs but there is no built in support of mapping array index to string. It has to be coded manually like has been suggested earlier. The above example does the entire mapping manually coding by hand. At no point did i try arguing hash table being a primitive construct. But since you have to code whatever you chose, i suggested writing hash is a better approach and produces more readable code.

Comment: For a constant data structure with number of sub arrays approaching at least 100 as mentioned by the OP, i would say that would produce pretty ugly piece of code. A hash appears much more elegant, readable and easier to maintain for any new developer.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your intention correctly, you want to associate array with a string key, then i don't think this is possible using any built in construct in core c i.e. c arrays are only indexed by integers.

One can always write a hash table, but the mapping of string to index has to be done by the programmer himself.

In C++ you can use a map to achieve this but map is part of STL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an hashtable.

For example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

uintmax_t hash(const char *s) { /* ... */ }

static const char t[N][M];

void init_string(void)
{
    strcpy(t[hash("foo")][0], "bar");
    strcpy(t[hash("foo")][1], "awe");
    /* etc */
}

char *get_string(const char *s)
{
    return t[hash(s)];   
}
```

To do:

- set `N` and `M`;
- defines the `hash` function;
- handle collisions;
- handle other errors.

Comment: my needs are very basics but your solution is nice for a dynamic solution with read/write constraints!