# ideal data type for an array in C, level 2

Tags: c, arrays, static, initialization

Now that [I found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162733/ideal-data-type-for-an-array-in-c) to statically initialize my array of items, I need a more complexe structure and instead of a char* as a value, I need a struct (named atom_s).

```
typdef struct atom_s {
  const char *val;
  const char *filter;
} atom_t;

struct
{
  const char *key;
  const atom_t **values;
} key_to_values[] =
{
  { .key = "foo", .values = (const atom_t *[]) { NULL } },
  { .key = "bar", .values = (const atom_t *[]) { { .val = "foo", .filter = "bar" }, NULL } },
};
```

The problem is: I don't know how to initialize an atom_s inside the array declaration above or if it is even possible.
The second line of the array (with key = "bar") does not compile:

```
warning: braces around scalar initializer  
warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)[0]')
error: field name not in record or union initializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ 
   .key = "bar", 
   .values = (const atom_t *[]) {
       (const atom_t []) {
           { .val = "foo", .filter = "bar" }
           // how is the user going to know this array has one element?
       },
       NULL 
   }
},
```

Each element of the array pointed to by `values`, points to an array of `atom_t` (except the last, which is null). You might also need some way to terminate each of those inner arrays, unless they're always the same length.

Comment: Ok, a "dummy" atom_s value, like an empty string for val?

Comment: @Guid: that would do it (or NULL for `val`). Just so long as there is a way.